# is there a generic module for aframe to display an explosion

Tags: aframe, webvr

Looking for a small effect of an exploding object ( or something which can replace the current object and display an explosion instead ? )

I searched online without much success. Any idea if there is a component for aframe around ?

Comment: What about displaying a GIF instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly exploding but perhaps these could help:

https://github.com/zhyuzh3d/kksMagic

https://ngokevin.github.io/aframe-physics-components/